# How to know what config contains in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to know what is the configuration defined in development.rb and production.rb?

there is a lot of mystery into what is set.

Is there a way to see that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Have you tried opening those files in a text editor?

Comment: I mean, once the files are configured with the individual configuration, how do I see the complete configuration? even those that I don't set

Comment: among the reason I ask is that I want to see what files are in config.assets.precompile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know it is what you are looking for, but you can start a rails console with

```
> rails c
```

and then inspect the Application like

```
> <Projectname>::Application.env_config
```

or

```
> <Projectname>::Application.config
```

which will print out some config hashes of your application